# Limit number of characters with Django Template filter

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to output the first 255 characters of a description on a list of items and am looking for a method to get that.

Example: I have a variable that contains 300 or so characters.

I call that variable like this, `{{ my_variable|characterlimit:255 }}`

and it would return only the first 255 characters of that variable.

If this tag doesn't exist, I will simply create it (and suggest that it goes into django), but I wanted to make sure it didn't before I took the time to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If the "my_variable" is a string, you can take advantage of the [slice filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#slice), which treats the string as a list of characters. If it's a set of words, the rough equivilant is [truncatewords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) - but that doesn't quite sound like your need.

`truncatewords`also adds an ellipsis `...` at the end of the truncated result.

Usage would be something like

```
{{ my_variable|slice:":255" }}
```

Answer (score 67):

There is an [official built-in filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars):

```
{{ variable|truncatechars:255 }}
```

Comment: This will put ellipsis ("...") behind the strings which are truncated (and not behind the ones which are not truncated). Slice doe not put ellipsis behind it. My advise: use truncatechars.

Comment: Agreed with the above. This will be correct in most situations (e.g. displaying a long URL without obstructing the hyperlink).

Answer (score 8):

A more simple way by using the standard template tag is:

```
{{ variable|stringformat:".10s" }}
```

In this case the 10 is the position argument and for a string it is the maximum number of characters to be displayed.

Comment: this is working for me... for some reason "slice" is not working now !! any idea, why ?

Answer (score 7):

If do you want to truncate by word, take a look at this
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars

Comment: In fact - you're linking to 'truncatechars' here, which does exactly what OP requested (but was added after OPs question was asked)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist unfortunately. There are moves to implement it, but it's still in the design stage (well, implemented, but waiting for design decision), as described [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5025).

Patch attached to that ticket contains implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Using a templatefilter for truncating your text isn't really suitable for a responsive design. Therefore you could also use css to truncate your text that is responsive. I know the OP asked to do this with a django templatefilter.

You can achieve a responsive truncated text using this:

```
.class {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```