# Jinja - how to force truncate when value exceeds specified field width

Tags: jinja2, truncate

I have started with the following ninja2 template, but If the value of the 2nd column is > the specified width, it simply prints the entire string and the rest of the columns shift right.

```
{{ "%-7s"|format(tbl[3]) }}      {{ "%-12s"|format(tbl[5]) }}    {{ "%14s"|format(tbl[6]) }}
```

The problem I want to solve is how to truncate the second column when (and only when) the tbl[5] value exceeds the column width.

Any ideas.  I've googled, but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried the truncate function:

```
{{ "foo bar baz qux"|truncate(9,true,'') }}
```

Like first parameter is the length the second tells you if you want to truncate exactly at length(if true) or truncate from a complete word. The third is the ellipsis, in this case a I removed the default `...` and I put a blank instead.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It does.  Thanks.  However it spawns another question.  If I use the trunc function, how do I specify alignment (right, left, center) at the same time.  I've looked at the docs and everything I try fails:

Comment: OK.  I found the answer :    {{ '{:^9}'.format("foo bar baz qux")|truncate(9,true,'') }}

Comment: In django jinja, it's `truncatechars:9` as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23686559/4126114)

Comment: For [Jinja 2.9+](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.9.x/templates/#truncate) the default leeway changed to `5`, so you'll need `{{ "foo bar baz qux"|truncate(9,true,'',0) }}` (note the fourth parameter).